# Why this error keeps occurring?

Tags: perl, dbi

I have inherited some old code. It gets a list of categories from a MySQL database table. I'm tasked with adding multilevel support to them. I've almost got it done, but for some reason it just errors out when I go to try the app in action.

The error is (you can also see it at http://detyams.ru/?cat=1):

> Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.18/DBI.pm line 2074,  line 2231.

```
sub catlist
{
    my $self=shift;
    state $sth=$self->db->prepare(q/SELECT c.cat_id,c.cat_name,COUNT(pn.p_id) as cnt from category c
    LEFT JOIN price_new pn ON (pn.cat_id=c.cat_id) GROUP BY pn.cat_id WHERE c.parent_id=?/);
    $sth->execute(0);
    my @catlist=$sth->fetchall_arrayref({}); # <- this call leads to the failure in the deep of DBI code.
    foreach my $item (@catlist)
    {
        $sth->execute($item->{cat_id});
        $item->{children}=$sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
    }
    return @catlist;
}
```

I've looked up some examples of using the DBI methods in there (like http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=284436#loh), all appear to be in accord with my code.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Oh, so, it just turned out if in case of a query syntax error (`WHERE` clause was placed in wrong position) `fetchall_arrayref()` appears to report cryptic errors instead of the underlying problem. Found out by checking server logs.